# Accessing data in a multidimensional JSON object

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON object returned from an API call in the `$result` variable, and my problem is that I need to access the `"name"` item in each list, but it doesn't work

```
{
"status": "success",
"data": {
    "lists": [
        {
            "id": "0032",
            "name": "Stan",
            "status": "active",                
        },
        {
            "id": "0043",
            "name": "David",
            "status": "active",                
        },
        {
            "id": "2323",
            "name": "Robert",
            "status": "pending",                
        }
    ]
}
}
```

**Code :**

```
 if (isset($result)) {
        $json_object = json_decode($result, true);
        echo $json_object['status'];
        echo $result;

        if ($json_object['status'] == 'success') {
            $json_object2 = $json_object['data'];
            foreach ($json_object['data'] as $key => $value){                                   
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2){
                    echo $key2 . " : " . $value2 . "</br>";
                }
            }   
        } else {
            echo $json_object['data'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<?php

$result = '{"status":"success","data":{"lists":[{"id":"0032","name":"Stan","status":"active"},{"id":"0043","name":"David","status":"active"},{"id":"2323","name":"Robert","status":"pending"}]}}';

$json_object = json_decode($result, true);

foreach($json_object['data']['lists'] as $item)
{
    echo $item['name']."<br>";
}

?>
```